# Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\MyP\resources\views\pekerja\index.blade.php)

Tags: sql, laravel, model-view-controller, relationship

i have problem 'Trying to get property of non-object' on this code. please someone check this code for make me clear. TQ

index.blade.php

````
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="idUnit" class="control-label col-sm-3">Unit :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <select name="idUnit" class="form-control input-sm" id="idUnit" disabled="disabled">
            <option value="">Sila Pilih...</option> ---> error on this code!
            @foreach ($KodUnit as $unit)
                <option value="{{ $unit->id }}"
                    @if(isset(request()->idUnit) && request()->idUnit == $unit->id)
                        selected="selected"
                    @endif
                >{{ $unit->nama }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>```
kodUnit model:
````

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class KodUnit extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'kod_unit';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'kod', 'nama'];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Comment: This is whole code?

Comment: @Davit i just c/p error code here.

Comment: I mean in your blade

Comment: Your laravel version?

Comment: @ Davit oh its too long sir..em laravel 5.2

Comment: Tmp comment(delete) this part `@if(isset(request()->idUnit) && request()->idUnit == $unit->id)
                        selected="selected"
                    @endif` if error hidden that mean wrong part here

Comment: @Davit i have post the full code in blade.php sir

Comment: I look it but here I did not notice any wrong part. Only js part you can change to `unit     = "{!! $KodUnit->toJson() !!}"`

Comment: @Davit nothing change sir. still got same problem.